# could not convert string to float although what is inside the string ' ' appears to be a number

Tags: python, string, google-analytics, floating-point

I have some web traffic data downloaded from Google Analytics(downloaded as csv file) and cleaned the data into the following nested dictionary.

[The country dictionary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Z3Fp.png)

Then, I desired to do some arithmetic calculation such as adding up the 'Impressions' of all Key(8 countries in the photo).

```
def all_country_impressions(country_dict):
     impressions_summed = float(0)
     for country in country_dict:
         impressions_summed += float(country_dict[country]['Impressions'])
return impressions_summed
```

However, I am getting the error (could not convert string to float: '1,911,091')
I am a little confused because what is wrapped inside the quote characters '' seems to be a numeric type. Could someone help me look at my problem and offer help, please?

Comment: replace the comma values `float(country_dict[country]['Impressions'].replace(',',''))`

Comment: Thanks for asking your first question, ym8rk. @user70, could you turn your comment into an answer so that ym8rk can accept it?

Answer (score 0):

Replace the comma values with the blank:

```
float(country_dict[country]['Impressions'].replace(',',''))
```